# Store Theme object in objects in Spring Data Redis StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I'd like to store objects that have a theme object in Redis. At the moment I can store a normal object, even one that has another object in it.
But I'd need to include a Theme object.
A Theme interface looks like this:

```
public interface Theme {
    String getName();

    MessageSource getMessageSource();
}
```

A MessageSource interface looks like this:

```
public interface MessageSource {
    String getMessage(String var1, Object[] var2, String var3, Locale var4);

    String getMessage(String var1, Object[] var2, Locale var3) throws NoSuchMessageException;

    String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable var1, Locale var2) throws NoSuchMessageException;
}
```

But I'm getting a stackoverflow error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:381) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterCacheKey.hashCode(GenericConversionService.java:464) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getHash(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:214) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:246) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:226) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:253) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:190) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.toBytes(MappingRedisConverter.java:729) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeToBucket(MappingRedisConverter.java:537) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.access$1000(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:434) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.access$900(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:429) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.access$900(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:429) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeCollection(MappingRedisConverter.java:518) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.access$800(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:417) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.access$900(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:429) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingRedisConverter.java:395) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: Looks like you have an object cycle in your data model. Care to provide a reproducible test case?